# Python Correlation index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation

Given a data frame "df", I need to obtain the correlation index between mean price and total volume for Region = "California".

***Given Dataframe:***
[image]

***Correlation index between California mean price and total volume:***

```
cali_mean = df.groupby('Region').get_group('California')['AveragePrice'].mean()
max_volume = (df.groupby('Region')['TotalVolume'].sum()).max() #Output: 1028981653.17

# Correlation index between California mean price and total volume
df[cali_mean].corr(df['max_volume'])
```

When I tried determining the correlation index between California's mean price and total volume, I got the following error message. Is there a way to fix this?

***Error message***

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3620             try:
-> 3621                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622             except KeyError as err:

~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 1.3939644970414187

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/wv/42dn23fd1cb0czpvqdnb6zw00000gn/T/ipykernel_18660/3247367876.py in <module>
      1 # Correlation index between California mean price and total volume
----> 2 df[cali_mean].corr(df['max_volume'])

~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3503             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3504                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3505             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3506             if is_integer(indexer):
   3507                 indexer = [indexer]

~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3621                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622             except KeyError as err:
-> 3623                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3624             except TypeError:
   3625                 # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

KeyError: 1.3939644970414187
```

Comment: cali_mean is a mean value not a column, which error implies.

Comment: Also note that there is not any correlation between two numbers.

Comment: @keramat How do I determine the correlation index then if mean value is not a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the correlation is a measure of two vectors. So you can use:

```
df = pd.read_csv('avocado.csv')
temp = df[df['Region']=='California']
temp['AveragePrice'].corr(temp['TotalVolume'])
```

Output:

-0.7913852550045145

Comment: What do the "tv" and "av" represent here? Meaning how do I fill in the values for "tv" and "av" so that it reflects mean price and total volume of California region?

Comment: How do you know which values to fill the vector "av" and "tv" with?

Comment: When I filled the vector with my data, I got "nan" output. Is this expected as you mentioned?

Comment: Can you send a sample of your data in a format that I can copy?

Comment: My data is in a form of a CSV file. Is there a way to send you that?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MTvt3Lr1awKjWWRWOW2Dwo1RsjkeHook/view?usp=sharing This is the CSV file.

Comment: Edited the answer based on your data.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I appreciate it.